# How to change the element connectivity?

Tags: acegen

After each load step, I check if the stress has reached a critical value. If this is true, I would like to change the elements connectivity as shown in the figure. Is it possible to do it with AceFem even during the analysis?[image]

Comment: I assume that you would still like to keep the same topology (Q1) for all elements? Maybe you could solve this by adding some special line element (topology LX, 3 nodes) attached to two nodes on the right side of element 1 and enforcing the proper position of the third node in between by penalty constraint. It looks non-trivial...

Comment: What have you done so far, or are you simply begging for code?

Comment: It seems like you also want to insert an additional node. O1 and O3 elements hav 5 nodes, so this is not Q1 element. It is all possible to do, but it is not trivial. Can you provide a simple working example?

Comment: @Pinti.
I don’t want to keep the same topology Q1 for all elements. e.g., element 1 has now 5 node which does not coincide with Q1-element.

Comment: @AliHussein  I didn't know that pentagonal finite elements exist? Maybe you could simplify your example and first try to merge triangular elements to quads? Anyway, we would appreciate more information and something like minimal working example in your question.

Comment: @BHudobivnik
That is exactly what I want to do. As far as I know. After SMTAnalysis[] , we can only change the boundary conditions (AceFem Doc.: Removing the prescribed boundary conditions).

Comment: @Pinti
I am using the virtual element method. This method allows the use of arbitrary polygonal (2D) and polyhedral (3D) elements. I'll try to give a simple example, which illustrate my questions.